# ReCaptcha not displaying on browser

Tags: php, recaptcha

I ran into a weird problem today. I was trying to implement the new ReCaptcha v2 into my website and it works fine. I tested it on all computers at home however on only 1 of them it decided not to work. It gave me a:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

My site is by default served over HTTPS but I checked and that's not the issue. This because I tried to load the same page without HTTPS but it still gave the same error. The weird thing however is that all the other devices at home I tested it on just worked fine.

So what could be the issue that this one computer isn't working?

If you need specific details about that one computer just ask.

Comment: One of your computers might have out of date certificates. Are you calling ReCaptcha via its HTTPS url?

Comment: Yes. I am loading the script like this: `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`